# PHP How to group json object id

Tags: php, json

i searched in so and google, but i could not find any method for my problem. There are answers to similar questions.
And also, if i have over an hundred objects in json, foreach can be slow.

Thanks in advice

```
$list = json_decode($string);
$grouped = array();


foreach($list as $object) {

    if(!array_key_exists($object->id, $grouped)) {
         $newObject = new stdClass();        
         $newObject->id = $object->id;
         $newObject->tip = $object->tip;
         $newObject->kar = array();         
         $grouped[$object->id] = $newObject;
    }

    $taskObject = new stdClass();
    $taskObject->tur = $object->kar->tur;
    $taskObject->tid = $object->kar->tid;
    $taskObject->pric = $object->kar->pric;
    $grouped[$object->id]->kar[] = $taskObject;

}

$grouped = array_values($grouped);
$json = json_encode($grouped);

var_dump($json);
```

my json..

```
{
    "roms": [{
            "tip": "bane",
            "id": "327034409",
            "kar": [{
                "tur": "ray",
                "tid": "989530150",
                "pric": "3.25"
            }]
        },
        {
            "tip": "bane",
            "id": "327034409",
            "kar": [{
                "tur": "kay",
                "tid": "989530151",
                "pric": "1.67"
            }]
        },
        {
            "tip": "bane",
            "id": "327034409",
            "kar": [{
                "tur": "tay",
                "tid": "989530152",
                "pric": "5"
            }]
        },
        {
            "tip": "yane",
            "id": "327034410",
            "kar": [{
                "tur": "kay",
                "tid": "989530153",
                "pric": "14"
            }]
        },
        {
            "tip": "yane",
            "id": 327034410,
            "kar": [{
                "tur": "tay",
                "tid": "989530154",
                "pric": "3.75"
            }]
        },
        {
            "tip": "yane",
            "id": 327034410,
            "kar": [{
                "tur": "lay",
                "tid": "989530155",
                "pric": "1.3"
            }]
        },
        {
            "tip": "rula",
            "id": "327162383",
            "kar": [{
                "tur": "ray",
                "tid": "989855757",
                "pric": "3"
            }]
        },
        {
            "tip": "rula",
            "id": "327162383",
            "kar": [{
                "tur": "rok",
                "tid": "989855758",
                "pric": "1.83"
            }]
        },
        {
            "tip": "rula",
            "id": 327162383,
            "kar": [{
                "tur": "lok",
                "tid": 989855759,
                "pric": "4.4"
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to group forms object in same tur/id.
and i would like to group json object which has same id, tur/ tidname. For example like this
How i want..

```
 {
    "roms": [{
            "tip": "bane",
            "id": "327034409",
            "kar": [{
                "tur": "ray",
                "tid": "989530150",
                "pric": "3.25"
            }, {
                "tur": "kay",
                "tid": "989530151",
                "pric": "1.67"
            }, {
                "tur": "tay",
                "tid": "989530152",
                "pric": "5"
            }]
        },

        {
            "tip": "yane",
            "id": "327034410",
            "kar": [{
                "tur": "kay",
                "tid": "989530153",
                "pric": "14"
            }, {
                "tur": "tay",
                "tid": "989530154",
                "pric": "3.75"
            }, {
                "tur": "lay",
                "tid": "989530155",
                "pric": "1.3"
            }]
        },

        {
            "tip": "rula",
            "id": "327162383",
            "kar": [{
                "tur": "ray",
                "tid": "989855757",
                "pric": "3"
            }, {
                "tur": "rok",
                "tid": "989855758",
                "pric": "1.83"
            }, {
                "tur": "lok",
                "tid": "989855759",
                "pric": "4.4"
            }]
        }

    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the correct solution.

I've changed a few parts,  like looping over the roms ($list->roms) instead of over the list. And tur, tid and pric are not direct children, but they are the first elements of an array.

```
$list = json_decode($string);
$grouped = array();

foreach ($list->roms as $object) {
    if (!array_key_exists($object->id, $grouped)) {
        $newObject = new stdClass();
        $newObject->id = $object->id;
        $newObject->tip = $object->tip;
        $newObject->kar = array();
        $grouped[$object->id] = $newObject;
    }

    $taskObject = new stdClass();
    $taskObject->tur = $object->kar[0]->tur;
    $taskObject->tid = $object->kar[0]->tid;
    $taskObject->pric = $object->kar[0]->pric;
    $grouped[$object->id]->kar[] = $taskObject;
}

$grouped = ['roms' => array_values($grouped)];
$json = json_encode($grouped);

var_dump($json);
```